# Using global variables in multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading

We are using Colibri iMX7D for our product development. Our application is running on embedded Linux with GTK+3.

In our application, there will be a thread running always to get data from ADC and the data will not be processed until I get a interrupt from GPIO. So, to implement this, I have a global boolean variable. In the interrupt thread (libsoc), I will be setting the boolean to be true. In the ADC thread, I will be processing the data if that variable is true. When another GPIO interrupt occurs, I will set the variable to be false in the interrupt thread.

After lot of googling, I found it is not good to use a shared variable inside multiple threads and found concepts like mutex and semaphores. It is a little bit confusing as both looks similiar and I am not sure about what to use for my application.Suggestions or directions to implement this are welcome.

Comment: Remember, it's not usually a problem to have multiple *readers* of some variable. The issues with threading often come about when you have multiple *writers*. Look at read and write locks if you want to implement it properly. Those depending on the value should lock for reading, check it, and do whatever. The writer must obtain a write lock, which may involve waiting a short amount of time for that resource to be obtained.

Comment: Hello sir..Thank you for your quick answer. I am having a thread which always reads a global variables and other few threads which writes the global variables only in interrupts. So In this  case, is it really necessary to implement locks for reading thread or locking only on writing thread is enough?

Comment: It's generally the case that only the writer needs a lock if you're dealing with a very simple value, like a boolean. For more complex structures where it takes time to write it out, as in the operation is *non-atomic*, then you'll need to be a lot more careful.

Comment: Ok sir. So for this kind, which is more suitable mutex or semaphores?

Comment: @NaaiSekar semaphore has particularity of having gloable visibility. This allows you to synchronize both processes (different PIDs) but also threads. As you are in a multithreaded context like yours, a mutex is suffisant.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problem of data consistency during `simultaneous` read and write access, your architecture as presented has a major disadvantage in terms of **performance**. Indeed, the fact of using a boolean variable, this forces you to probably loop in your ADC thread in something that looks like this:

```
while ( bDataPresent == false ) ...
```

You should know that in this case, your `ADC thread` is in permanent execution, therefore, it consumes resources: `CPU`, `memory`, ...

This is not the case when you use `semaphore` (or other synchronization mechanism) because when the thread is blocked on a semaphore call, it does not consume as much resource.

Comment: Hello sir...Thanks for your answer. But my ADC thread will be taking data from ADC using SPI everytime and the acquired data need to be processed by the value of boolean variable.So in my case the ADC thread need to be run all the time and it should not wait till the condition to become true.

Comment: @NaaiSekar I dont know in detail how you intend to use your boolean variable, but I just wanted to warn you about the performance aspect of your application. If you can present the skeleton of interactions between your threads, we can help you.